# UIAlertview in Tab bar icon

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

how to make tab bar icon clickable. Once I tap on it should get a pop-up or an alert (`UIAlertView`).

I know how to present `UIAlertView`, but i want to have alert on click the tab bar icon.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to set your `UITabBarController` to its delegate and use the method `didSelectItem`

In `.h` add `<UITabBarDelegate>`

In `viewDidLoad`

```
  yourTabBarController.delegate=self;
```

Then use the delegate method:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{

     if(item == yourAlertTab)

     {

        //Code to show alert.

     }
}
```

Comment: @christien What exactly isn't working ? Can you edit your question ? And add the code ?

Comment: when i put my tab in if condition if(item= tab1) and code to alert tab ..it does not show any alert

Comment: can u give me your email id so that i can email u my code.and u can understand

Comment: @christien, is `tab1` a `UITabBarItem` ?, just paste the code in your question i'll look into it.

Comment: ya correct ! tab1,tab2,tab3 are the names of my tabs i defined. and i tried with in IF condition by putting tab1 but not working sir.and i dont have 15 reputation to post as i m new here! so i cant ..help

Comment: @christien, are you sure your tab bar controller is entering the didSelectItem delegate method? If it isn't entering, maybe you forgot to set it as delegate. Or you've forgotten to add <UITabBarDelegate>, guessing you solved this as you've asked a new question.

Comment: no I have not solved that issue..that new ques is another issue for me.i ve taken ur mail id and mail u for solution in nyt.as i dont ve tht code now.thanks

Comment: @christien, i'll look into it, but give me some time, i'm middle of something. Don't mind.

Comment: @christien, i took a look, the green hurts my eyes :D, but will look into it further when i've time. I'll reply it over mail, not here.